# React Native FlashList - numColumns varies depending on the content

Tags: react-native, flash-list

I have a list of documents and i want to display them like on the image below, using a Shopify Flash List in React Native.
If a document type is a video, i want it to take the whole width of the screen, all the other documents should be displayed by two in a row.
I tried to set numColumns property to 1 or 2, and modify getColumnFlex. But i can not achieve the layout i want.

[image: see image]

Index.js :

```
<View 
style={{flexDirection: 'row',
    minHeight: 2,
    width: '100%',
}>
            <FlashList
              data={documentsList}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
              refreshControl={
                <RefreshControl refreshing={loadingDocuments} onRefresh={fetchAllDocuments} />
              }
              renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                <DocumentsList
                  documentsList={documentsList}
                  document={item}
                  index={index}/>
              )}
              estimatedItemSize={200}
            />
</View>
```

DocumentList.js

```
 <TouchableOpacity
      key={document.id}
      style={{
        width: document.type === 'video' ? '100%' : ’50%’,
        height: document === 'video' ? 280 : 210,
      }}>
{/* Code of my component*/}
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure possible with FlashList, but if there is a possibility to use `FlatList`, items wrapping can be controlled with [flexWrap](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox#flex-wrap) in [columnWrapperStyle](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#columnwrapperstyle).

```
<FlatList
  columnWrapperStyle={{ flexWrap: 'wrap' }}
  numColumns={99}
  data={...}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <View
      style={{
        width: item.type == 'video' ? '100%' : '50%',
        height: item.type == 'video' ? 280 : 210
      }}>
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightgrey', flex: 1, margin: 10 }} />
    </View>
  )}
/>
```

Comment: With columnWrapperStyle={{ flexWrap: 'wrap' }} , if i have 5 items and first one is a video , 
the first item takes 100% width of the row ✅, 
second item takes 50% of the width, but it is alone in it's row ❌, 
third one and forth one are good ✅, 
and fifth one is alone in it's row